# Não estou conseguindo vincular o layout com o viewBinding, alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Estou uns 3 dias preso no mesmo problema.

Não estou conseguindo vincular o layout à classe utilizando o viewBinding, utilizando o arquivo build.gradle...

Já tentei recriar o projeto, e variar de todas as formas possíveis (que eu consegui imaginar) essa configuração....

Eu inicialmente fiz de acordo com o que eu conhecia:

```
buildFeatures { viewBinding true }
```

Não funcionou, depois fui até o site do android e vi essa nova configuração:

```
viewBinding { enabled = true }
```

Mas mesmo assim ele acusa erro, "sublinha" a palavra enabled. Também tentei:

```
viewBinding { enable = true }
viewBinding { enable }
viewBinding { enable true }
 
buildFeatures { viewBinding { enabled = true } }
buildFeatures { viewBinding.isEnabled } 
 
// Dentre diversas outras possibilidades...
// O problema que o colega citou acima também aconteceu
```

Também tentei definir o viewBinding globalmente, no gradle.properties (dica do chatGPT):

```
android.viewBinding.enabled=true
```

Também tentei olhar para o import:

```
import com.example.mvvmstudy.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
// Não me parece estar aqui o erro
```

Qual pode ser o problema?
Eu já tentei reescrever o projeto do zero e nada kkkk

O projeto é um exemplo de como funciona o MVVM, eu tentei definir um botão para lançar um toast, só pra ver se o botão estava vinculado, mas não consigo vincular ele dessa forma...

Repositório: https://github.com/DaniloVolles/MVVMStudy

Answer (score 0):

> Eu inicialmente fiz de acordo com o que eu conhecia:
>
> > buildFeatures { viewBinding true }

Provavelmente não funcionou porque você deve estar usando Kotlin DSL ao invés de Groovy nos seus arquivo do gradle.

Para Kotlin a sintaxe é um pouco diferente.
Dentro de "android" você vai adicionar dessa forma (com sinal de atribuição):

```
android {
    // ...
    
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    
    // ...
```